# Is it possible to keep the text below or above the ttk Checkbutton?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am coding an alarm GUI in python using tkinter/ttk. For this section, my code looks like

```
    self.checkFrame = ttk.Frame(self.alarm1)
    self.checkFrame.grid(row = 1)
    self.mon = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'MON')
    self.mon.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    self.tue = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'TUE')
    self.tue.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    self.wed = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'WED')
    self.wed.grid(column = 2, row = 0)
    self.thur = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'THUR')
    self.thur.grid(column = 3, row = 0)
    self.fri = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'FRI')
    self.fri.grid(column = 4, row = 0)
    self.sat = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'SAT')
    self.sat.grid(column = 5, row = 0)
    self.sun = ttk.Checkbutton(self.checkFrame, text = 'SUN')
    self.sun.grid(column = 6, row = 0)
```

Everything looks good except the text appears on the right of the button. I was wondering if there is anyway that I can move those texts below the button.

Comment: You can always use `Checkbutton` without text and put `Label` below or above.

Comment: wouldn't it make it difficult to make sure they are aligned when I adjust the window size?

Comment: Normally `grid` doesn't change widgets size when you resize window - so there is no problem with alignment. If you use grid options which change that behavior then probably you will have to add some options like `grid(sticky=...)` or `label(anchor=...)` .